# Gravitational waves: novel or confirmatory?

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, gravitational-waves

If the rumors are true and gravitational waves have been detected, would we learn any new fundamental physics from them? Or is this simply an important confirmation of a prediction of general relativity that doesn't give us new insight into current unsolved problems?

Comment: That entirely depends on whether the actually detected waves a consistent with the predictions of GR for them or not, no?

Comment: My impression was that if the waves are not consistent with GR, they will not be detectable with the equipment and algorithms they are using. In other words, something other than than what GR predicts will be filtered out. Perhaps not...

Comment: I would put it into the unlikely category that we will learn anything new about general relativity, but we should definitely learn something important about the sources of these waves in time. Having said that, rumors in physics are fun but completely useless. So is a one time detection by one detector. Until the other facilities catch up, I wouldn't put too much faith in this result.

Comment: I assumed the rumor was that they had made a 5-sigma type of discovery, not just a single detection on one detector. I read it on lubos motl site...but no details. I'll continue to spread this rumor until I find out the facts.